# AWS IAM - EC2 - Restrict access to specific subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a policy to limit users to only run instances in a certain subnet, but the following isn't working (anonymising the account ID, Subnet ID and SID)

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "SID",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeImages",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT NUMBER:subnet/subnet-id",
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT NUMBER::network-interface/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT NUMBER::instance/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT NUMBER::volume/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT NUMBER::image/ami-*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT NUMBER::key-pair/*",
            "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:ACCOUNT NUMBER::security-group/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

ALso I have tried this, which is also not working

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "SID",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeImages",
            "ec2:DescribeInstances",
            "ec2:DescribeTags",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:subnet": "subnet-id"
            }
        },
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Would appreciate any input people have, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using the subnet arn instead of the subnet ID in the condition block?

Answer (score 1):

AWS has documented this, please refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_instances-subnet.html